# Cordova android 4.x backbutton event not fired when resources is not local (using http)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

Its working in my current 3.7.1 version, but when I upgraded to 4.x, the back button is not working, to reproduce (working with non http source) :

1. cordova create test
2. cd test, change the index.js :

   onDeviceReady: function() {
       app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
       document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
           alert('back');
       });

   },
3. cordova platform add android
4. cordova build android

but if the config.xml was changed for example :

and rebuild again,the back button is not alerting, what I try to resolve :

1. @index.html add
2. Try inspect device using chrome and there's no error, and device ready event is fired

Anybody can help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@polymerAngular,
I've got some demo Apps, that are exclusively for testing Phonegap Events. You can test all in pairs or singularly. The Backbutton works with 3.5.0.

All Events: https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Events-test

Backbutton: https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-PhysicalButton-test

**2nd response for @polymerAngular**

Apparently Phonegap Build does NOT support 4.x from Cordova. I have asked Phonegap Support for verification and clarification on this forum post at nitboi

*Need verification and clarification on phone-gap-version*
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/need-verification-and-clarification-on-phone-gap-version?rfm=1

I will update after they respond.

TIA
Jesse

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, I think i'm using cordova CLI not the phonegap, or it is the same source ?

Comment: Okay. Support responded. The answer suggest that versioning is not an issue. This means you can use my code, with one change. Move config.xml from the www directory to the project root. IT should then build with both Cordova CLI and Phonegap CLI. --- On your question about *Cordova vs. Phonegap*. [PG FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/). The short answer is Phonegap was donated as Cordova to Apache.org. Now Cordova is used, as the code base,  by Phonegap, Ionic, Sencha Touch and others.

Comment: To be clear, use my code to find your issue. As my code is working, tested, and freely available. Best of Luck.

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask, there is no <content src="http://" /> in your code, the problem I had with back button is with content src in the http somewhere, it run great when running locally in the android

Comment: @polymerAngular, from what I read about the *HTML element <content>*, it is a [Shadow DOM component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content). I would NOT expect it to work with that webview library. It MIGHT work with [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/), but you would need to [move to cli-5.1.1](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/bookmarks/fromSupport.html). ALSO, i do NOT have any experience with this HTML element; this is the first I have heard of this.